# Capture changes for the last 30 minutes from tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need only to capture the changes for last 30 minutes only in for the below query:

```
  SELECT 
  P.COL1, P.COL2, P.COL3, C.COL1, C.COL2, T.COL1, T.COL2, P.COL4+T.COL4 AS "COL4"
  FROM
  TABLE1 P,
  TABLE2 C,
  TABLE3 T
  WHERE
  PM.COL1(+)  = C.COL1
  AND T.COL2(+) = C.COL2
```

TABLE 1, TABLE 2 AND TABLE3 each has a modification date column, but I think adding the following to the query logically won't be right and it might degrade the query execution performance

```
 SELECT 
 P.COL1, P.COL2, P.COL3, C.COL1, C.COL2, T.COL1, T.COL2, P.COL4+T.COL4 AS "COL4" 
 FROM
 TABLE1 P,
 TABLE2 C,
 TABLE3 T
 WHERE
 PM.COL1(+)  = C.COL1
 AND T.COL2(+) = C.COL2
 AND P.MODIFICATION_DATE > SYSDATE - 30
 AND C.MODIFICATION_DATE > SYSDATE - 30 
 AND T.MODIFICATION_DATE > SYSDATE - 30;
```

Also not all the 3 tables are updated at the same time, TABLE2 as an example last modification_date was yesterday at 11:00 am while TABLE3 modification_date is today at 2:00 pm.

How can I capture the latest 30 minutes changes between the tables?

Comment: Unrelated, but: even Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` operator for outer joins.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know but this is the original query on prod env. and somehow my manager wont accept any change before I can generate the 30 mins report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I capture the latest 30 minutes changes between the tables?

You can find the last 30 minutes activity for each `COL1` and `COL2` from one table using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT C.*,
         MAX( MODIFICATION_DATE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY COL1, COL2 ) AS last_mod_date
  FROM   TABLE2 C
)
WHERE  MODIFICATION_DATE >= LAST_MOD_DATE - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

If you just want the last 30 minutes for the entire table (rather than for each combination of `COL1` and `COL2`) then remove the `PARTITION BY COL1, COL2` clause to just leave it as `OVER ()`.

So to get the last 30 minutes of each table you can do:

```
WITH C AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT C.*,
           MAX( MODIFICATION_DATE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY COL1, COL2 ) AS last_mod_date
    FROM   TABLE2 C
  )
  WHERE  MODIFICATION_DATE >= LAST_MOD_DATE - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
),
P AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT P.*,
           MAX( MODIFICATION_DATE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY COL1 ) AS last_mod_date
    FROM   TABLE1 P
  )
  WHERE  MODIFICATION_DATE >= LAST_MOD_DATE - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
),
T AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT T.*,
           MAX( MODIFICATION_DATE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY COL2 ) AS last_mod_date
    FROM   TABLE2 T
  )
  WHERE  MODIFICATION_DATE >= LAST_MOD_DATE - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
)
SELECT P.COL1, P.COL2, P.COL3, C.COL1, C.COL2, T.COL1, T.COL2, P.COL4+T.COL4 AS "COL4" 
FROM   C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN P
       ON (    P.COL1  = C.COL1 )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN T
       ON (    T.COL2 = C.COL2 );
```

Without some sample data and seeing what your expected results are it is difficult to know if you need/want the `PARTITION BY` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect in multiple different ways.  First, `sysdate - 30` subtracts 30 *days* not 30 *minutes* from the value.

From what you describe, the following may be what you want:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT P.*
      FROM TABLE1 P
      WHERE P.MODIFICATION_DATE > SYSDATE - 30 / (24 * 60)
     ) P FULL JOIN
     (SELECT C.*
      FROM TABLE2 C
      WHERE C.MODIFICATION_DATE > SYSDATE - 30 / (24 * 60)
     ) C
     ON P.COL1 = C.COL1 FULL JOIN
     (SELECT T.*
      FROM TABLE3 T
      WHERE T.MODIFICATION_DATE > SYSDATE - 30 / (24 * 60)
     )
     ON T.COL2 = C.COL2;
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake of sysdate - 30 I meant sysdate -30/(24*60) but I missed it :D
I will try the from clause you described and will eliminate the original join and will update with results.